# Como insertar un nuevo elemento a un objeto de Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#crearMetaCompuesta',
        data: {
            rangos_creados: {
                0: {
                    min: null,
                    max: null,
                    result:null
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            additem: function () {

            }
        }
    })
```

En `additem()` quiero agregar un nuevo index con sus respectivos valores a `rangos_creados`, es decir agregar n elementos con min, max , result

¿Cómo puedo ir agregando elementos? En internet encuentro `vue.set` pero es para `arrays[]` , no he encontrado para este tipo de objetos.

gracias.

Comment: Pero eso debería ser un array de objetos, ¿no?

Comment: como así?, la verdad no comprendo

Comment: Lo que estás «creando» en rangos_creados tiene más el aspecto de un array de objetos.

Comment: aah, pero necesito llenarlo con más items, siempre lo hago con la respuesta del axios y solo lo igualo, pero necesito hacerlo desde el front con un método

Answer (score 1):

Seria mejor si `rangos_creados` fuera de tipo array, y así en `additem` bastaría con colocar lo siguiente `this.rangos_creados.push(nuevo_elemento)` y quedaría algo así

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#crearMetaCompuesta',
        data: {
            rangos_creados: [
                {
                    min: null,
                    max: null,
                    result:null
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            additem: function () {
                this.rangos_creados.push({
                    min: 10,
                    max: 100,
                    result: null
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

De la forma que actualmente lo tienes también es posible solo que necesitarías crear atributos dinámicamente del objeto `rangos_creados` quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#crearMetaCompuesta',
        data: {
            rangos_creados: {
                0:{
                    min: null,
                    max: null,
                    result:null
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            additem: function () {
                this.rangos_creados[nuevoIndex] = {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 100,
                    result: null
                };
            }
        }
    })
```

El problema con eso es que tendrías que tener el control de los índices que vayas creando, si no puede pasar que sustituyas algún índice ya existente

Comment: +1 Esta es la respuesta correcta